# Aliasing an ActiveRecord attribute in a has relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider a relationship like this:

```ruby
class BuyableComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cost
end

class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quantity

  belongs_to :buyable_component

  def total_cost
    # This should be buyable_component.cost, but how do I make an alias so
    # I can just use 'cost'?
    cost * quantity
  end
end
```

I have a `buyable_components` table and a `cart_items` table. Like the comment describes, I would like to be able to use `cart_item.cost` instead of `cart_item.buyable_component.cost`. `alias_attribute` seems to be close to what I need, but not quite.

I'm looking for a way to declare this for all attributes of `BuyableComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :cost, :to => :buyable_component
end
```

this should work I suppose